# Unable to get result using object

Tags: c#, .net

```
public object My()
{
    List<string> mystring = new List<string>();
    mystring.Add("aaaa");
    mystring.Add("bbb");           
    return mystring;   
}
```

In Main

```
 Program p1 = new Program();
 object test = p1.My();
 Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Even if converted to `Tolist()` I'm getting `System.Collection.Generic.List`

How do I convert my result into List and display all elements?

Comment: Why are you returning `object`?

Comment: actually it is a dummy code, My actually code is dynamically generated by and I'm executing it using Roslyn , and I want to return a string , list etc depending on case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the object (test) back to `List<string>` and then iterate over all the elements in `List<string>` to print them.

Try This:

```
Program p1 = new Program();
object test= p1.My();

List<string> lst = (List<string>) test;
foreach(string item in lst)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: If I want to do it dynamically and do not know the return type then?

Comment: you meant to say  how to cast the object  ,if the List type is unknown right?

Comment: @Neo If you don't know the type of a `List`, you could just cast it to `IList` interface.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for if you don't know the type the `List` will return. So if you don't know the type, but you know that there will be some sort of `List` returned and you want access the `List` functionality you can cast the result to an `IList` interface and your program won't care for which type generic `List` specializes.

```
Program p1 = new Program();
var test = p1.My();
var lst = (IList) test;
foreach (var item in lst)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

From `WriteLine` method documentation ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx))

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the
>   ToString method of value is called to produce its string
>   representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard
>   output stream.

As documentation says the ToString method of `List<string>` is called with `WriteLine` method.

And the default behavior of `ToString` is to return string representation of type of instance. ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx))

> The default implementation of the ToString method returns the fully
>   qualified name of the type of the Object, as the following example
>   shows.

In order to print out contents of list you need to change return type of your method to `IEnumerable<string>` and for example use `Join` method of `string`. see this:

```
  public static IEnumerable<string> My()
  {
      var mystring = new List<string>();
      mystring.Add("aaaa");
      mystring.Add("bbb");
      return mystring;
  }
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var test = My();
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", test.ToArray()));

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
      Console.ReadLine();
  }
```